A semi-injective binary operation on the naturals which is not injective
We all know what an injective operation is. I have come up with a new definition, which I call semi-injectivity. Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than or equal to $2$, let $S$ and $T$ be sets, and let $f$ be a function from $S^n$ to $T$, where $S^n$ is the $n$-th Cartesian power of $S$. I call $f$ semi-injective if, whenever $f(x_1,...,x_n) = f(y_1,...,y_n)$, the set $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is equal to the set $\{y_1,...,y_n\}$. Note, I said the sets, not the tuples. Also, the reason I restricted $n$ to not be $1$ is because, in that case, semi-injectivity is the same as injectivity. Anyway, my question is, is there a binary operation from naturals to naturals which is semi-injective but not injective?

Sure - consider $$f(x,y)=2^{\min\{x,y\}}3^{\max\{x,y\}}.$$ More generally, if $S$ is an infinite set, fix an ordered pairing operation $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $S$ and a linear ordering $\triangleleft$ of $S$ and consider the function $$(x,y)\mapsto \langle\min\{x,y\},\max\{x,y\}\rangle$$ where $\min$ and $\max$ are calculated with respect to $\triangleleft$.

Sure, you just have countable sets here  so instead of $\mathbb N$ think about the set of primes $\mathbb P$.  Now, let $f: \mathbb P\times \mathbb P\to \mathbb N$ be defined by the product, $f(p,q)=p\times q$.
Equivalently, let $F:\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ be defined by $F(n,m)=p_n\times p_m$ where $p_k$ denotes the $k^{th}$ prime.
